# Is there any workaround for calling constructors without new keyword?

Tags: typescript, proxy, this, metaprogramming, decorator

I have a hard time finding a way to call constructors of `es6` classes without the use of a `new` keyword. I know this is unadvised but my use-case requires it.

I need to access `this` before constructor calls. Wrap it in proxy and then pass it to the original constructors. Following code works but only when typescript build target is set to `es5`/`es3`:

```
const raw = Object.create(OriginalClass.prototype);
const proxied = new Proxy(raw, ...);
OriginalClass.prototype.constructor.call(proxied, args);
```

Exact same code produces an error:

```sh
VM63:28 Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor SomeClass cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at Object.construct (eval at <anonymous> (main-3.js:1239), <anonymous>:28:49)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (main-3.js:1239), <anonymous>:43:24)
    at main-3.js:1239
```

when targeting `es2015` or higher.

For anyone interested why I might need something like that, [here is an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true&emitDecoratorMetadata=true&target=1&ssl=22&ssc=63&pln=22&pc=7#code/MYewdgzgLgBANiA5gWQK5QIZQJbgjAXhgAoBKALhgzAE9CA%20EgKBhhACdtFswM4BhPFHapgUDpTABTAO4kAdIoztEEStRoBtALqkGVWkz0FGAbxYwA9JZgABKBAC0XMBykX2UqKnZgY0uQAFdhAADxpiDi4ePkFIYVFxdgAaGHNWVlB4kTFiAHlObl4BOAwINQMaVOVVdVo9dIzMoRh2DDkiPIAjACspMXlgTywpfMKYkrKIeQAHEPEoGhmpUgBuJgsm6zsHZ0RXT02MrOgYObDsKQATQn9ZGGCwiLaZVMam1kQvYkwVLzqqjAANZSGiUaCcMCIBpHD6tLw%20Py-L5QTQgmjadZw1gAX2SsIyEG%20yP%20lVS6PBwh4iFSADc%20KgpACYdjjngQHApPIEIhiAADADKXhwUJgJNRACIACSmdE4iXaMUgGD0uCM4i0ygy1WMvFipZMmAyxbLEAAMxVDKkONIinkfLWBKa4rRoMVRB1UixrPh3l8YpEXqdMBxBJtGzh2wAKgALbD4GQcIH4cBwOjYC0mqQQIbYGawUAAWxm2FKOHAYpqXhg8ZgEuzAFYJWx2PBs9MCQVosV%20KVyrN5iAs4MhDkkoM%20HBiOdQpcrtUVBBHQTPH6-DO597cRYbescesNrYeWhMOXIGQmMA%20-gBSBC1Je1M0hYZqgunBsMAqJTIYhbhKMEAiVvVfd9PxgLof2pA9mmyRIODIZ9nTjaYun-LoMIlHcmFDS8WgOQs%20AASXiahgCkW4AhgW970fcoLyYAjiNIsByPkNCiAlAAhHjgI2E4OS5HliCYuASOgMiVjwyBBO5JARI4QixJYtiulIfj2U5OTeVE8TMFYiieAkgzzWou8H2vNYrBsBIpAAQiAA). There are tons of other use cases that could highly benefit from something like this... for example all kinds of reactivity libraries (1 simple class level decorator could automatically mark all properties as observables and all methods as actions - even ones set lazily/dynamically).

Comment: How about a static method which will create a class for you with an optional parameter?

Comment: I don't think that's relevant to my problem.

Comment: I think the answer to this question is probably "no, you can't do this", but maybe you should be asking it as a `javascript` question for `ES2015` or `ES6` as opposed to `typescript` to get more expert eyes on it?